# Filter object by value - Redux

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, filter, redux

I am trying to figure out redux but I am stuck. I have an input that is in the header section and within the body section, I have a component that receives the data from the parent and renders them as list items. So far so good.

I have wired my input search text to fire a redux action on each key press.

#### my actions file

```
export const jobsFilterDisplay = (jobsList, filterValue) => async dispatch => {
    if (!filterValue){
        console.log("you should call fetch all again");
        console.log(filterValue);
        jobsFetchAll();
    } else {
        console.log("original list");
        console.log(jobsList); // list of jobs - original and unfiltered
        console.log(typeof jobsList); // returns object
        console.log("filter value"); // 
        console.log(filterValue); // my search text input value
        //
        // I think this is where I am supposed to filter the original list 
        // and dispatch an event with the filtered object as the payload
        // in my reducer, I will assign the payload to my list 
        // my list component should update automatically and render updated list
        // dispatch({ type: JOBS_LIST_FILTERED, payload: filterValue }); 
    }
}
```

I want to be able to search by customer name or any attribute. Whenever I tried `_.filter` or anything like that, I always ended up either `not a function` or `undefined` and I've been trying for more a long time.

#### my json example - part of it

```
{"jobs":[{"id":1,"ticket":{"number":121,"quote":12321,"tech":"Tech 1","date":"06-22-2017","status":1},"customer":{"name":"John","address":"USA"}},{"id":2,"ticket":{"number":1231231,"quote":21123,"tech":"Tech 4","date":"06-22-2017","status":2},"customer":{"name":"Doe","address":"CANADA"}}]}
```

Any help is appreciated . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.filter() for this. Are you using lodash currently? That is also possible. But I recommend Array.prototype.filter() approach. Here's how you can do it.

```
const payload = 
  [{"id":1,"ticket":{"number":121,"quote":12321,"tech":"Tech 1","date":"06-22-2017","status":1}, "customer":{"name":"John","address":"USA"}},
{"id":2,"ticket":{"number":1231231,"quote":21123,"tech":"Tech 4","date":"06-22-2017","status":2},"customer":{"name":"Doe","address":"CANADA"}}]


  function filterByCustomerName(customerName, payload) {
    return payload.filter(job => job.customer.name === customerName);
  }

  const job = filterByCustomerName('Doe', payload);
  console.log(job);
```

Anyway If you really need to use lodash, make sure you import it like this. Then use the filter from the lodash library. But still I don't see any fair reason for you to go for it.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
function fetJobByCustomer(customerName, payload) {
     return _.filter(payload, job => job.customer.name === customerName);
  });
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !